# MS SQL How to store grouping query result in a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got a grouping query which I'd like to capture in another table.
Here the source query:

```
SELECT [OSGBref10m],[EpsScannedCellIdentity],[EpsScannedBand],count(*) as Nmeas,AVG([EpsScannedRsrp])
  ,RANK() OVER (Partition by [OSGBref10m] order by AVG([EpsScannedRsrp]) desc) as RankInPixel     
  ,MAX ([EpsScannedRsrp]) as [EpsRsrpMax]
  ,MIN ([EpsScannedRsrp]) as [EpsRsrpMin]
  ,MAX ([EpsScannedRsrq]) as [EpsRsrqMax]
  ,MIN ([EpsScannedRsrq]) as [EpsRsrqMin]
  ,MAX ([EpsScannedRsCinr]) as [EpsSinrMax]
  ,MIN ([EpsScannedRsCinr]) as [EpsSinrMin]
  ,Round(STDEV ([EpsScannedRsrp]),2) as [EpsRsrpStdDev]
  ,Round(STDEV ([EpsScannedRsrq]),2) as [EpsRsrqStdDev]
  ,Round(STDEV ([EpsScannedRsCinr]),2) as [EpsSinrStdDev]
  FROM [LteScanSumOSGB_800] as o
  GROUP BY o.[OSGBref10m],o.[EpsScannedBand],o.[EpsScannedCellIdentity]
  HAVING count(*)>=1
```

What would be the easiest way to record the result of this query into a table?

```
SELECT * INTO tableName from TableName seems not to be suitible here.
```

Comment: Why do you have repeating columns and values? If you give your columns unique names, `select ... into` shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT [OSGBref10m],[EpsScannedCellIdentity],[EpsScannedBand],count(*) as Nmeas,AVG([EpsScannedRsrp])
      ,RANK() OVER (Partition by [OSGBref10m] order by AVG([EpsScannedRsrp]) desc) as RankInPixel     
      ,MAX ([EpsScannedRsrp]) as [EpsRsrpMax]
      ,MIN ([EpsScannedRsrp]) as [EpsRsrpMin]
      ,MAX ([EpsScannedRsrq]) as [EpsRsrqMax]
      ,MIN ([EpsScannedRsrq]) as [EpsRsrqMin]
      ,MAX ([EpsScannedRsCinr]) as [EpsSinrMax]
      ,MIN ([EpsScannedRsCinr]) as [EpsSinrMin]
      ,Round(STDEV ([EpsScannedRsrp]),2) as [EpsRsrpStdDev]
      ,Round(STDEV ([EpsScannedRsrq]),2) as [EpsRsrqStdDev]
      ,Round(STDEV ([EpsScannedRsCinr]),2) as [EpsSinrStdDev]
      into sometable
      FROM [LteScanSumOSGB_800] as o
      GROUP BY o.[OSGBref10m],o.[EpsScannedBand],o.[EpsScannedCellIdentity]
      HAVING count(*)>=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt

```
SELECT * INTO tableName from TableName
```

Tries to store the result into the same table you are reading from...

If you want to store this temporarily you might try

```
SELECT * INTO #SomeTempTable from TableName
```

If the table should be persisted, the easiest is

```
SELECT * INTO SomeNewPhysicalTable from TableName
```

And if you want to do this cummulative ("add" the result of a second call) just use `SELECT ... INTO SomeNewPhysicalTable` for the first call and then

```
INSERT INTO SomeNewPhysicalTable SELECT * FROM...
```

The syntax `SELECT * INTO ...` wants to create a new table.

**Important**: The resultset must carry unique names for each column.

### Btw: I was lazy...

You should always use a specific column list rather than the `*`!